# Why is my dropdown nav with overflow: hidden blocking the page equal to the height of the nav?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, responsive-design

[height blocking website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dXNR.jpg)This is while working on a screen size equal to a phone. I really have no idea on how to get this nav's height to not block any of my site's other elements. For instance if I scroll down where a button is I cannot click it due to the height of the nav even though it is not expanded.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Edit: I added a picture to show how the drop down height is blocking parts of the website. Once I scroll far enough down I am unable to click on the button.

```
<header>
  <nav>
   <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.html">shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="sport.html">sport</a></li>
    <li><a href="read.html">read</a></li>
    <li><a href="explore.html">explore</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
```

```
header {
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 75px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(63, 63, 63, 0.65));
}

nav {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 55vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 29px;
}

nav .nav-links {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
      -ms-flex-align: start;
          align-items: flex-start;
  opacity: 1;
  /* only to show when class is added */
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
          transform: translateY(-100%);
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.nav-links.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
  /*only shows when class is added */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
          transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```
const revealNav = () => {
  const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

  hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hamburger.classList.toggle('is-active');
  }, false);

  hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('is-active');
  });
}

revealNav();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header postion is fixed. This means that all elements outside the header will fall 'underneath' this header...

If you could make a real world example it might be better to understand your problem.

It is a mix between having the `position: fixed` on your header and the fixed `height` you have on the header and nav. Below example is something that more or less may fix your problem. With some media queries and extra logic it should work for you.

```js
const revealNav = () => {
  const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('nav');
  const navLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

  hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hamburger.classList.toggle('is-active');
  }, false);

  hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navLinks.classList.toggle('is-active');
    nav.classList.toggle('is-active');
  });
}

revealNav();
```

```css
header {
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(63, 63, 63, 0.65));
}

nav {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 29px;
  height: 0;
  transition: height ease-in-out .5s;
}
nav.is-active {
  height: 55vh;
  height: auto;
}

nav .nav-links {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
      -ms-flex-align: start;
          align-items: flex-start;
  opacity: 1;
  /* only to show when class is added */
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
          transform: translateY(-100%);
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.nav-links.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
  /*only shows when class is added */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
          transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <button class="hamburger">
    menu
  </button>
  <nav>
   <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.html">shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="sport.html">sport</a></li>
    <li><a href="read.html">read</a></li>
    <li><a href="explore.html">explore</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>

<div style="height: 500px; background-color: blue; position: relative;">
  <button>submit</button
</div>
```

Comment: I added a photo now I will give it a try with your solution.

Comment: So this has worked, I appreciate your help. Is there a way though to have the header "fixed" without using fixed? I personally like it when the header is always visible.

thank you again.

Comment: Last update, I added a container around the entire container with height: 0; then I was able to apply position: fixed; to the original header with no negative effects to the web page, so far...

Comment: @Rambus_Jarbus: I was glad I could help. Been off the radar since my last reply. I see you've come to a solution with help of my answer. Hope this will be a final solution for your problem.